# In selenium how to access a iframe having only src attribute?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am unable to locate this popup window:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:'&lt;html&gt;&lt;/html&gt;';" style="position: fixed; width: 583px; height: 441px; left: 374px; top: 158px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 3001;" scrolling="no" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:'&lt;html&gt;&lt;/html&gt;';" style="position: fixed; width: 583px; height: 441px; left: 374px; top: 158px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 3001;" scrolling="no" tabindex="-1"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way could be to just locate the outer container of the iframe, and target on your specific iframe in the container.

like

```
driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@id = "my-id"]//iframe");
```

Comment: not working....thanks .. I have observed that iframes are getting identified by using findElement(By. CSSSelector) more precisely than by Xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use XPath in order to get the frame, you can do something like:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe"));
```

which will get the first instance on the iframe on the page. If you have multiple iframes then you will need to be more explicit in your xpath.

To specifically answer your question, though, you can use xpath like:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<the contents of the src here')]"));
```